# Update javascript variable on html after event- Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, variables, events, reactjs

I am working on JSX and I have the following issue

JS

```
var results ="";
results = value that changes;
```

HTML

```
<div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: results}}></div>
```

I have the variable results that changes when a button is pressed. Originally the value is "" and after the event it becomes another string. I want to display the new string every time the button is pressed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add that variable to the state of your component. Firstly, add

```
getInitialState() {
  return { value : "initialValue" };
}
```

Or if using ECMA6,

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { value : "initialValue" };
}
```

When you want to change it, call

```
this.setState({ value : "newValue" });
```

And on the `render` method, use:

```
render() {
  return <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.value}} />;
}
```

Or something like that. Then when your state changes, React will redraw it, calling `render` again.

BTW, you should avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if possible. If you want, you can comment more about what you are doing to see if there are alternatives.

If your value does not contain HTML, for instance, you should use:

```
render() {
  return <div className="content">{this.state.value}</div>;
}
```

Which is much nicer and safer :)

Comment: good answer, but should be {{__html: this.state.value}}  (note that you forgot the "state." after the "this."

Comment: You are correct, @JeffMcCloud! Already updated the answer. Thanks, my friend :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply it seems that it doesn't work.
What I want to do is to update a javascript variable with different values and show the results on html. Your answer gives me an error"getInitialState was defined on App, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?"

Comment: @Spy that's because you are using ECMA6 and I was unaware of it. The syntax has changed a bit, I will update my answer. I'm not sure if I got your question indeed, but I think I did. You could try to elaborate more; how familiar are you with react?

Comment: It worked using your way. I am new to reactjs so I had to troubleshoot for a while. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Spy You're welcome :) I added an example without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you can check if it fits your case.